Generating MAC from key and data
I am trying to generate Message authentication code (MAC) based on a given key and data file in order to verify message integrity. I tried to do it via the following method. However, the MAC generated does not seem to match. How is my method wrong?
I need to utilise the Crypto.Hash library
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

hasher = SHA256.new()
hasher.update(key_data)
hasher.update(data)
mac_generated = hasher.digest()


Please, provide a [mre] (we don't know what key_data is, nor data, ...) and make clear what result of your [mre] isn't what you would have expected, and what you were expecting.
